# Colorir Linha Selecionada Angular JS e Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-3

Como faço pra colorir a linha selecionada em uma table?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="p in produtos" ng-click="info(p)" 
  ng-class="{'info': ??}">
```

Só não estou conseguindo encontrar uma condição para colorir somente a linha selecionada.

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: Com linha selecionada você quis dizer a linha em que o mouse está sobre, ou no seu objeto `p` terá alguma propriedade que dirá isso?

Comment: A linha que eu cliquei com o mouse, no caso o angular tem o $index que retorna a posição que está selecionada, gostaria de colorir essa linha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução seria você criar uma variável:

```
$scope.selected = '';
```

E ao clicar em uma `tr` atribuir o $index ou id do elemento a esta variável, depois basta verificar qual o valor e aplicar a classe, deste modo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in produtos" ng-click="selected = $index" ng-class="{'info': selected == $index}">
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando: https://plnkr.co/edit/BALHDT?p=preview

Comment: Perfeito, fiz um pouco diferente, mas funcionou: usei $index === rowSelected no ng-class, e no ng-click setei $scope.rowSelected = index; obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Se a tua intenção é marcar e desmarcar, uma opção é criar uma variável `boleana` que será "ligada" ou "desligada" ao clicar.

```css
.azul {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <ul>
    <li 
        ng-repeat="x in names" 
        ng-click="selected = !selected" 
        ng-class="{'azul': selected}">
      {{ x }} - {{ $index }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Dessa maneira poderá se secionar todos os itens ao mesmo tempo, o que
>   depois percebi que não responde a pergunta do AP, porém pode ser útil.